# Existe alguma forma de usar self Execute functions em vb6?

Tags: funções, visual-basic-6

Em javascript podemos escrever isto de vários modos:

```
(function () {
    console.log("Olá");
})();

(function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}());

! function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}();

void function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}();
```

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em vb6, e queria utilizar algo do tipo de uma função self-invoke para não precisar declarar uma função no escopo global do meu form, resumindo quero chamar uma função à qual só utilizarei uma vez dentro desta função e não utilizarei mais.

Alguém sabe se existe uma forma de fazer isso sem ser utilizando gambiarra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não, VB6 só aceita Functions ou Subs declarados no escopo do form. Trabalhei com VB6 algum tempo e nunca vi nada do tipo.

Mais informações:
https://www.vbtutor.net/lesson14.html

Comment: Encontrei isso, não é o ideal, mas resolveu meu problema https://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch05/05-05-GotoAndGosub.htm